# Rails text_field tag default character limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a default character number limit for the `<%= f.text_field :user_name %>` ??
Or do I need to specify one? I did not find anything online. The `user _name` is a string and it should be by default 255 the limit right? Do I need to add `size: '255'` ?

Comment: maximum limit depends on database we use for our app. you can specify it in ur model, by using "validates :user_name, :length => { :maximum => 100 }"

Answer (score -1):

This is the signature of `text_field`:

```
text_field(name = "", value = nil, size = 40, maxlength = nil)
```

As you can see, by default the number of shown characters (`size`) is set to 40. This is most often overwritten by your custom CSS.

The `maxlength` parameter is optional and will limit the amount of characters that a user can input in a field.

In general, I think it is better not to limit the input of a field and instead handle that stuff through validations like it is mentioned in the comments.